# Calling a SalesForce API from C# - GET vs POST

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce

I need to call a SalesForce API in order to query an account for any changes. I have previously created a program that submits data to SalesForce via an API (using HTTP POST) and it works fine. For the new API call I only have the name of the REST service and that I have to use HTTP GET. Should the method call be the same other than using ...

```
request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
```

instead of

```
request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, restQuery);
```

Should the oAuth token generation remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 public string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";

        // Add parameters to post
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;
        System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
        os.Close();

        // Do the post and get the response.
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        if (resp == null) return null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
```